# How to reset data of NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am using two [NumberPicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker)s to display province(`mProvincePicker`) and city(`mCityPicker`) data in my app. When user changes province data, city data should be changed accordingly. I reset the `mCityPicker` data in `NumberPicker.onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal)`. But it does not work well and an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` crash the app.

Here is my code:

```
public class AreaPickerDialog extends Dialog implements OnValueChangeListener, OnClickListener {
    static final String TAG = "AreaPickerDialog";

    private NumberPicker mProvincePicker;
    private NumberPicker mCityPicker;
    private Button mCancelBtn;
    private Button mOKBtn;

    private AreaUtil mAreaUtil;
    private List<Area> mProvinces;
    private int mAreaId;
    private int mProvinceId;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public AreaPickerDialog(Context context, Handler handler, int areaId) {
        super(context);
        mAreaUtil = AreaUtil.getInstance();
        mProvinces = mAreaUtil.getProvinceList();
        mAreaId = areaId;
        mProvinceId = mAreaUtil.getProvinceIdByAreaId(areaId);
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_area_picker);
        mProvincePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np_province);
        mCityPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np_city);
        mCancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        mOKBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

        initProvinceData();

        mProvincePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        mCityPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        mCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mOKBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initProvinceData() {
        if (mProvinces != null && mProvinces.size() > 0) {
            String[] provinceNames = new String[mProvinces.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < provinceNames.length; i++) {
                provinceNames[i] = mProvinces.get(i).getProvincename();
            }
            mProvincePicker.setDisplayedValues(provinceNames );
            mProvincePicker.setMinValue(1);
            mProvincePicker.setMaxValue(mProvinces.size());
        }
        mProvincePicker.setValue(mProvinceId);
        initCityData(mProvincePicker.getValue());
    }

    private void initCityData(int provinceId) {
        List<Arealist> cities = mAreaUtil.getCityListOfProvince(provinceId);
        if (cities != null && cities.size() > 0) {
            try {
                int min = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(0).getAreaid());
                int max = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(cities.size() -1).getAreaid());
                String[] cityNames = new String[cities.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++) {
                    cityNames[i] = cities.get(i).getName();
                }
                mCityPicker.setValue(0);
                mCityPicker.setDisplayedValues(cityNames);
                mCityPicker.setMinValue(min);
                mCityPicker.setMaxValue(max);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                ILog.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (mProvincePicker.equals(picker)) {
            initCityData(mProvincePicker.getValue());
        } else if (mCityPicker.equals(picker)) {
            mAreaId = mCityPicker.getValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_cancel:
            dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_ok:
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MineActivity.MSG_UPDATE_AREA);
            msg.arg1 = mAreaId;
            msg.sendToTarget();
            dismiss();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And logcat error trace:

```
12-30 23:09:26.560: E/InputEventReceiver(5620): Exception dispatching input event.
12-30 23:09:26.560: W/dalvikvm(5620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ddf438)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=14; index=15
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.updateInputTextView(NumberPicker.java:1840)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(NumberPicker.java:1423)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at com.meishai.app.dialog.AreaPickerDialog.initCityData(AreaPickerDialog.java:88)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at com.meishai.app.dialog.AreaPickerDialog.onValueChange(AreaPickerDialog.java:100)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1855)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1641)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1106)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.onTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:886)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
12-30 23:09:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.dispatchTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:944)
    ....
```

I am reseting the `minValue,maxValue and DisplayedValues` to reset the `NumberPicker` data and not working, so what is the right way?

Comment: length is 14 index starts from 0 accessing index 15 you get the exception. debug using break points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I look into the source code of [NumberPicker.java](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/numberpicker/NumberPicker.java), find that it will recompute the data and refresh UI in `setMinValue(int minValue)` and `setMaxValue(int minValue)`. When set the new minValue, it will compute using new minValue and old maxValue, then error occured.

So, I modify a little of the `NumberPicker`: set value only in `setMinValue(int minValue)` and `setMaxValue(int maxValue)`, and update UI in `setDisplayedValues(String[] displayedValues)`. When data of `NumberPicker` changed, just reset the minValue、maxVaule and displayedValues. Note that `setDisplayedValues(String[] displayedValues)` MUST be called at last.

Here is what I modified:

`NumberPicker.java`:

```
public void setMinValue(int minValue) {
    if (mMinValue == minValue) {
        return;
    }
    if (minValue < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minValue must be >= 0");
    }
    mMinValue = minValue;
    if (mMinValue > mValue) {
        mValue = mMinValue;
    }
    //boolean wrapSelectorWheel = mMaxValue - mMinValue > mSelectorIndices.length;
    //setWrapSelectorWheel(wrapSelectorWheel);
    //initializeSelectorWheelIndices();
    //updateInputTextView();
    //tryComputeMaxWidth();
    invalidate();
}

public void setMaxValue(int maxValue) {
    if (mMaxValue == maxValue) {
        return;
    }
    if (maxValue < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxValue must be >= 0");
    }
    mMaxValue = maxValue;
    if (mMaxValue < mValue) {
        mValue = mMaxValue;
    }
    //boolean wrapSelectorWheel = mMaxValue - mMinValue > mSelectorIndices.length;
    //setWrapSelectorWheel(wrapSelectorWheel);
    //initializeSelectorWheelIndices();
    //updateInputTextView();
    //tryComputeMaxWidth();
    invalidate();
}

public void setDisplayedValues(String[] displayedValues) {
    if (mDisplayedValues == displayedValues) {
        return;
    }
    mDisplayedValues = displayedValues;
    if (mDisplayedValues != null) {
        // Allow text entry rather than strictly numeric entry.
        mInputText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    } else {
        mInputText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    }
    boolean wrapSelectorWheel = mMaxValue - mMinValue > mSelectorIndices.length;
    setWrapSelectorWheel(wrapSelectorWheel);
    updateInputTextView();
    initializeSelectorWheelIndices();
    tryComputeMaxWidth();
}
```

`AreaPickerDialog.java`:

```
private void initCityData(int provinceId) {
    List<Arealist> cities = mAreaUtil.getCityListOfProvince(provinceId);
    if (cities != null && cities.size() > 0) {
        try {
            int min = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(0).getAreaid());
            int max = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(cities.size() -1).getAreaid());
            String[] cityNames = new String[cities.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++) {
                cityNames[i] = cities.get(i).getName();
            }
            mCityPicker.setMinValue(min);
            mCityPicker.setMaxValue(max);
            mCityPicker.setDisplayedValues(cityNames);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            ILog.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an ugly but working solution.

Answer (score 22):

check for Call `setDisplayedValues(null)` before `setMaxValue` in onClick.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24322319/2624806

Comment: The answer in the Reference should be the best one

Comment: Great solution +1

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem and I fixed it without modifing `NumberPicker.java`. Here is the code for your reference.

```
private void initCityData(int provinceId) {
        List<Arealist> cities = mAreaUtil.getCityListOfProvince(provinceId);
        if (cities != null && cities.size() > 0) {
            try {
                int min = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(0).getAreaid());
                int max = Integer.parseInt(cities.get(cities.size() -1).getAreaid());
                String[] cityNames = new String[cities.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < cityNames.length; i++) {
                    cityNames[i] = cities.get(i).getName();
                }
                int maxV = mCityPicker.getMaxValue();
                if (max> maxV){ 
                    mCityPicker.setMinValue(min);
                    mCityPicker.setValue(0);
                    mCityPicker.setDisplayedValues(cityNames);
                    mCityPicker.setMaxValue(max);
                }else{
                    mCityPicker.setMinValue(min);
                    mCityPicker.setValue(0);
                    mCityPicker.setMaxValue(max);
                    mCityPicker.setDisplayedValues(cityNames);
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                ILog.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @lu yuan , it works like a charm :) so the answer above should set as right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just set displayedValues to null before resetting number picker like below:

```
 pickerWard.displayedValues = null

 pickerWard.maxValue = values.size - 1
 pickerWard.displayedValues = values
```

Comment: this is the best answer to reset value

Answer (score 0):

looking the code of NumberPicker you're using:

```
private boolean updateInputTextView() {
/*
* If we don't have displayed values then use the current number else
* find the correct value in the displayed values for the current
* number.
*/
        String text = (mDisplayedValues == null) ? formatNumber(mValue)
                : mDisplayedValues[mValue - mMinValue];
```

you can see that's using mMinValue before you call setMinValue.

Try setting minValue and maxValue, before set the displayed values.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what my former code like. It doesn't work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it do helped me. I have posted my solution.